# Blackberry ObjectListField on click

Tags: blackberry, listfield

How to get selected row from blackberry objectlistfield, when user clicks on list item?

Comment: Be more specific. (Short questions are bad)

Answer (score 2):

[getSelectedIndex()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ListField.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29)

You will also have to set the setChangeListener() and implement the corresponding methods like fieldChanged() and keyDown()

have you read the documentation before asking ? Do you have a more specific question ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    Field focus = list.getLeafFieldWithFocus();
    Dialog.alert("Focus String :: " + focus.getIndex());

    if (focus instanceof ListField) {
        ListField listField = (ListField)focus;

        Dialog.alert("Selected Index"+listField.getSelectedIndex());
        Dialog.alert("Selected List Value"+listField.getCallback().get(listField,
            listField.getSelectedIndex()).toString());
    }
    return true;
}
```